# Handling Depth Processing With The Kinect V2

Tags: python, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect-v2

I am currently trying to deal with processing the depth data for the Kinect V2. I wish to filter out all points that are not within a specific distance. The problem is I can't find reliable docs on how this could possibly be done, let alone on how to retrieve the depth data itself. If anybody has any experience with extracting the depth data from the kinect V2, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am currently using the pylibfreenect2 bindings for the openKinect library, but I am flexible with dependencies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably found answer to your question.If not then here is the solution.
There is open source library which is on github and called [OpenKinect-for-Processing](https://github.com/shiffman/OpenKinect-for-Processing) library. It is use friendly and easy-to-use library which runs on your browser. For quick tutorial you can check this [link](http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/) and look through this small youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmVNgdapJJM&index=1&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZMlWHdcy8hAGDy6IaoxUKf). On youtube tutorial you can find easy way for thresholding and extracting depth data. You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1eIg54clGo&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZMlWHdcy8hAGDy6IaoxUKf&index=3) for quick glance how he extracts and thresholds depth data.